# php header / redirect

Tags: php, facebook

I want to connect my website with the facebook. So I am trying to make a button that user sign in with there facebook.

What I want to do is: pass users data that I need to create their account from my index.php to test.php (because it is a test after that I will adapt it) ...
problem is I am not able to redirect to test.php ...
I can do that with a form and a button but I want to do it without any button ...

```
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   IdiotMinds - http://idiotminds.com
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Login with Facebook</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/oauthpopup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#facebook').click(function(e){
                    $.oauthpopup({
                        path: 'login.php',
                        width:600,
                        height:300,
                        callback: function(){
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        session_start();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['User']) && empty($_SESSION['User'])) { ?>
            <img src="images/facebook.png" id="facebook"  style="cursor:pointer;float:left;" />
        <?php } else { ?>
            <form action="test.php" method="post">
                <INPUT TYPE = "hidden" name="name" VALUE =<?php echo $_SESSION['User']['first_name'] ?>>
                <INPUT TYPE = "hidden" name="lname" VALUE =<?php echo $_SESSION['User']['last_name'] ?>>
                <INPUT TYPE = "hidden" name="email" VALUE =<?php echo $_SESSION['User']['email'] ?>>
                <INPUT TYPE = "hidden" name="location" VALUE =<?php echo $_SESSION['User']['location']['name'] ?>>            
                <input type="submit" name="submit"/>  /* without this one please */
            </form>
            <?php
            header("Location:test.php?name&lname");
            /*
            echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'. $_SESSION['User']['id'] .'/picture" width="30" height="30"/><div>'.$_SESSION['User']['first_name'].'</div><div>'.$_SESSION['User']['last_name'].'</div><div>'.$_SESSION['User']['email'].'</div><div>'.$_SESSION['User']['location']['name'].'</div>';    
            echo '<a href="'.$_SESSION['logout'].'">Logout</a>';    
            */
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There must not be any output before the `header()` call!

Read the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).